# Images are shrinking in my application - Android

Tags: android, android-manifest

I developed an application for android. I am having a problem with the display of my application on my mobile. I am using the HTC wildfire mobile having a resolution of 240 x 320. When I loaded my application into mobile the images which I used in my application became small ( Shrinking) look and feel is so bad. It is showing somewhat good in the emulator.

How can I get the actual images in my application (Without shrinking )?

Can anybody help me, please?

Thanks and Regards,

Kiran.

Comment: try to add multiple screen support in your App.

Comment: Use images according to your device size, not as your emulator size. I think you are using different size emulator skin for testing rather than your device size.

Comment: @Piyush or @sunit your comment is right, you can post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

[Different display resolutions on android phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322681/different-display-resolutions-on-android-phones/4322737#4322737)

Answer (score 0):

Are you fixing the size of the ImageView to be particular pixels? like 140px? don't do that, use wrap_content or fill_parent instead. use a mix and combination of various layouts to achieve what you want. try to never fix the width/height by specifying pixels, if its extremely necessary, use dip instead of px.

Comment: NO I have given wrap_content for all IamgeView and given width and height in dip only at necessary situation. Even it is getting Shrink.

Comment: As i am seeing the whole application is shrinking in the mobile. I tried by keeping images in small other application even in that also the same thing happened.

Comment: I feel that your mobile fone has quite dense screen, or amazingly weird resolution. :-?